How to create unique fields in MongoDB with Mongoose?
I am working on a Node.js project and using MongoDB with Mongoose (version -8.9.2).
I want to enforce uniqueness for certain fields in my database (e.g., email) to ensure no duplicates are allowed.
here is my user Schema
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: { type: String },
  lastName: { type: String },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
  },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  age: { type: Number, min: 18, max: 65 },
  gender: { type: String, uppercase: true },
  photoUrl: {
    type: String,
    default:
      "https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/05/79/55/26/360_F_579552668_sZD51Sjmi89GhGqyF27pZcrqyi7cEYBH.jpg",
  },
});


and app.js like this
const express = require("express");
const connectDB = require("./config/database");
const app = express();
const User = require("./models/user");
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/signup", async (req, res) => {
  const userObj = req.body;
  try {
    const newUser = new User(userObj);
    await newUser.save();

    res.send("User created successfully");
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
  }
});

even other validations works well I got issue with only unique:true
I can create multiple users with the same email??
with the postman I tried with this user object
{
"firstName": "test",
"lastName": "testlastname",
"email": "test@gmail.com",
"password": "test@123",
"age": 20,
"gender": "male"
}
and i could create new user multiple times with the same email even i set unuqe:true in the schema

This question is similar to: Mongoose Unique index not working!. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
